# Disable popup of cmd windows when using gitpython and py2exe?

Tags: python, git, gitpython

On using gitpython on Windows with py2exe, every operation that is invoked by gitpython results in a cmd popup window. It seems to be that gitpython is using subprocess internally. Is there a way to specify the following equivalent in gitpython?

```
creationflags=win32process.CREATE_NO_WINDOW
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The way to solve this is to do this for gitpython is by setting before using the Git() object.

```
Git.USE_SHELL=True
```